# Connection refused in SpringBootTest with WireMock

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, wiremock

I'm observing some behavior in my Spring Boot integration tests which I don't yet understand.

Given the following abstract base class which initializes "generic" test stuff; in this case `WireMock` and Spring's `WebTestClient`.

**AbstractSpringIT.java**

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public abstract class AbstractSpringIT {

    @RegisterExtension
    static WireMockExtension wireMockServer = WireMockExtension.newInstance()
            .options(wireMockConfig().dynamicPort())
            .build();

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void configureProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("app.backend-url", wireMockServer::baseUrl);
    }

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;
}
```

Then, there are two test classes which extend `AbstractSpringIT`.

**AnotherIT.java**

```java
public class AnotherIT extends AbstractSpringIT {
 
    @Test
    void should_pass() {
        wireMockServer.stubFor(get("/some-path").willReturn(ok()));

        webTestClient.mutateWith(mockOAuth2Client("keycloak"))
                .get()
                .uri("/some-path")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .is2xxSuccessful();
    }
}
```

**SomeIT.java**

```java
public class SomeIT extends AbstractSpringIT {

    @Test
    void should_pass() {
        webTestClient.mutateWith(mockOAuth2Login()))
                .get()
                .uri("/api/user")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
    }
}
```

Both test classes pass when started individually. When running them together, however, `AnotherIT` fails due to a `Connection refused: localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:39813`.

I could narrow it down to this:

- Running the tests in alphabetical order (controlled by Maven) makes both test clases pass, i.e. `AnotherIT` runs *before* `SomeIT`.
- Both test classes pass when each of them uses their own `WireMockExtension` and `@DynamicPropertySource`.